# ChartJs with try catch

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So I'm trying to make a JS function that uses `ChartJS`, the variable/data the fucntion gets, is a JSON object. The reason why I use try/catch is because the two lines under here:

```js
let labels = json_data.data.map(e => e.StartTime);
let data = json_data.data.map(e => e.StatusId);
```

Isn't always set if there is any data they are set, but if not is the only one set

```js
let data = json_data.message.map(e => e.message);
```

Unless on page load, then nothing is set.

The JSON object change when a `<Select>` dropdown is changed, and if there is data in one then the `canvas` is loaded, but if the user then select one with no data, I want the graft to be empty/destroyed, but I cant do this because I'm in a try catch, and if I define it in the catch too, then it says that the ID already is in use. What do I have to do to "reset/destroy" it in the catch?

```js
function chartJSLoad(json_data) {
    try {
        let labels = json_data.data.map(e => e.StartTime);
        let data = json_data.data.map(e => e.StatusId);

        console.log(labels);
        console.log(data);

        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvaschartjs').getContext('2d');

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    type: 'bar',
                    label: 'Bar Dataset',
                    data: data,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 150, 90)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 90)',
                    order: 2
                }, {
                    type: 'line',
                    label: 'Line Dataset',
                    data: data,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(150, 0, 90)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 90)',
                    order: 1
                }],
                labels: labels
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        stacked: true,
                    },
                    y: {
                        stacked: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        if (typeof json_data !== 'undefined') {
            myChart.destroy();
            alert(json_data.message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your chart is not initialized when you have an exception so myChart is undefined. How can you call myChart.destroy()? Let console.log(myChart) for debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the static method [`getChart`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/api.html#static-getchart-key) to check if a chart with that context already exists, if it does you get that chart instance which you can destroy:

```js
catch (error) {
  if (typeof json_data !== 'undefined') {
    let chart = Chart.getChart('canvaschartjs');
    if (typeof chart !== 'undefined') {
      chart.destroy()
    }
    alert(json_data.message);
  }
}
```

Live example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, options);

let chart = Chart.getChart('chartJSContainer');
if (typeof chart !== 'undefined') {
  chart.destroy() // Does not show anything because of this line, comment it out to show again
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that there was a `getChart` function :)